# ice candidate is not working properly in ios WebRtc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webrtc

i'm trying to develop a calling application using webRtc. ice candidates are generated properly on the caller side. But on the receiver side, after generating session description ice candidates are not getting generated. All the status of sender and receiver are same but I can't understand why it's still not working. I didn't attach the code here cause it's more than 2000 lines. I just need some possible/probable cause/issues regarding this as I'm new with webRtc.